# Xamarin Setting default Boolean value

Tags: xamarin.forms, sqlite.net

I am using sqlite-net-pcl and adding a new column to a database DTO and I wanted to set the default value to true and then once I have update the data it would update to the correct value. But the default is not working for me in xamarin.

> is there any other way to do this?

```
[NotNull]
        public boolean Istaxable  { get; set; } = true;
```

This will block me from doing a update.

```
   [NotNull, Default(value: true)]
```

Error default is unknown

DTO

```
public class DtoTaxableLink
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public bool IsTaxable  { get; set; } = true;
}
```

service

```
 await App.LocalDB.InsertTaxableLinksAsync(BuildDbTaxableLinkItem(    public Task<int> InsertTaxableLinksAsync(List<DtoTaxableLink> taxableLinks)
ListResponse.Data));
```

local db

```
public Task<int> InsertTaxableLinksAsync(List<DtoTaxableLink> taxableLinks)
{
return database.InsertAllAsync(taxableLinks, true);
}
```

Helper

```
 private static List<DtoTaxableLink> BuildDbTaxableLinkItem(List<TaxablelineLink> taxableLinks)
            {
                List<DtoTaxableLink> dtoTaxableLink= new List<DtoTaxableLink>();
    foreach (var taxink in taxableLinks)
                {
                    DtoTaxableLink dtoTaxableLink= new DtoTaxableLink();
                    dtoTaxableLink.IsTaxable  = taxableLinks.IsTaxable  ;              
                    dtoTaxableLink.Add(dtoTaxableLink);
                }
                return dtoTaxableLink;
            }
```

Comment: when you create a new instance of the class using the first method, is the value set to true?

Comment: Correct it is set to true for data in the database . But I can’t seem to add new data where it would be false .

Comment: so if you create a new instance, set it to false, and then insert it into the db, what specifically is happening?

Comment: I create the new instance set the default value to true using just the NotNull and equal true. Then start the process to update the data and the once it goes to update to false it errors

Comment: Something like 02-05 16:11:12.599 I/Choreographer( 8302): Skipped 1040 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-05 16:11:12.658 D/Mono    ( 8302): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('libe_sqlite3.so').
02-05 16:11:12.658 D/Mono    ( 8302): Searching for 'sqlite3_extended_errcode'.
02-05 16:11:13.116 D/Mono    ( 8302):

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  I don't think those messages have anything to do with this.  Are you actually getting a runtime exception?

Comment: No runtime error just the output window information

Comment: So how do you know there is a problem?  And again, please post the relevant code.

Comment: When I debug it I see if processing the data up until there needs to be data that is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you want to set the default value to true when using sqlite-net-pcl and adding a new column to a database.

You can do it through property itself, field default value not going change until another value going to set.Please take a look the following code:

```
 public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

    private bool _sel = true;
    [NotNull]
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _sel; }
        set { _sel = value; }
    }
}
```

Now you can see I set Selected property default value is True, then you can update this value that you want.